# Global Params in FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I try to retrieve the global param that i define in parameters.yml and config.yml

in FOSUserBundle.en.yml under registration, in message i try to  pass %myparam% and in my email.txt i try pass %myparam%:param like this

```
{{ 'registration.email.message'|trans({'%username%': user.username, '%confirmationUrl%': confirmationUrl,'%myparam%':myparam}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
```

but it dosen't works.
and can i insert html inside yml and new line?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your config.yml under fosuserbundle configuration.

```
confirmation:
    enabled:    true
    template:   MYMailBundle:Registration:email.html.twig
```

By doing this you are creating a twig template where you can render your variables and format your html how you want.

If you want to create a newline in your yml file I think you could do it by adding a \n.

Comment: i create the new template, but the global params dosen't read..in yml \n dosen't works. thanks

Comment: new line in yml i resolve:

splash:
   abstract: |            
            bla bla bla bla bla bla
            bla bla blabla bla bla
            bla bla bla!.

and in twig

<p>{{'splash.abstract'|trans({},'myfiletrans')|nl2br }}</p>